# How to register a generic interface by its type in DI container

Tags: asp.net-core, dependency-injection

I want to register some generic interfaces that can be resolved to their relevant implemented class. I'm using asp.net core's built-in Dependency Injection(**ServiceProvider**).

Assume my interface is like this:

```
public interface ICommandHandler<in TCommand> where TCommand :Command
{
    void Execute(TCommand command);
}
```

and my class are like these:

```
public class AddItem1CommandHandler : ICommandHandler<AddItem1Command>

public class AddItem2CommandHandler : ICommandHandler<AddItem2Command>
```

and my commands as it is obviously in interface constraint is like this:

```
public class AddItem1Command: Command
public class AddItem2Command: Command
```

So, I can register them one by one:

```
services.AddTransient<ICommandHandler<AddItem1Command>, AddItem1CommandHandler>();
services.AddTransient<ICommandHandler<AddItem2Command>, AddItem2CommandHandler>();
```

The problem here is that I'm forced to define a registration for per implementation. Now my question is that is there any way to register all of them in one line like this:

```
services.AddScoped<ICommandHandler<Command>, Command>();
```

I don't know how it can be possible or not with ServiceCollection.

Comment: If you want to create a Factory method that can somehow determine `which` command it should select that is a valid option.  I used to work on a service where dependencies were versioned and registered by name as v1, v2, v3, etc. and based on arguments or environment variables the old, current or next version was selected.  This let us deploy a new version without changing anything and this slowly dial up the percentage of users using vNext.  Once we got to 100% we made vNext the current value, dropped off vOld altogether and made vCurrent the new vOld.  It's some work, but worth it.

Comment: That's pretty similar to the scenario where the server needs to authenticate request using different schemes. I suggest you could follow the way by ASP.NET Core Team, i.e. creating a `CommandHandler` class which could resolve the correct handler by command.

Comment: checkout the open source package called scrutor

Answer (score 1):

`ICommandHandler<>` is a generic type and I get all implementation from Assembly.

```
public static void Register(Assembly assembly, IServiceCollection services)
{        
    var allCommandHandler = assembly.GetTypes().Where(t =>
        t.IsClass &&
        !t.IsAbstract &&
        t.IsAssignableToGenericType(typeof(ICommandHandler<>)));
    foreach (var type in allCommandHandler)
    {
        var allInterfaces = type.GetInterfaces();
        var mainInterfaces = allInterfaces.Where(t => t.IsAssignableToGenericType(typeof(ICommandHandler<>)));
        foreach (var itype in mainInterfaces)
        {
            services.AddScoped(itype, type);
        }
    }
}
```

And I call this method in the `dll` contains `CommandHandler`